# Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list appcompat in android

Tags: android, android-library, android-appcompat

When I add `appcompat` project as a library I get these errors:

```
- found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list appcompat in  android. 

- `aapt.exe` has stop working.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: The version of jar is not same of your app and the library, make them same.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Delete `android-support-v4.jar` from library and project. Then go in `<sdk>/extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos/` and copy `android-support-v4.jar` and paste in libs folder of both.

Comment: there is no libs folder in Support4Demos, any help?

Comment: @WasifKhalil Then create and see it works or not. I am not sure about this bcoz I have never faced any problem like this.

Comment: I think you will end up with the same lib compiled twice this way. Wouldn't be better to use only appcompat's `android-support-v4.jar`? I mean, delete the support.jar from your project's libs folder and add appcompat project as a library. 
Works in NetBeans (tested). In my Project View, the support.jar shows up as a library, but the jar is placed fisically in appcompat libs folder

Answer (score 12):

Generally you get this error when you add external library which already contains `android-support-v4.jar`file.

Here you can delete this `android-support-v4.jar` file from your libs folder. This will solve your problem.

Comment: If I delete android-support-v4.jar in my app Its show error on every line that include **R.** something.

Comment: did you try cleaning your project ?

Comment: this works fine with me
@JohnR try to refresh your project >> R Click >> Refresh

Answer (score 2):

I too had same problem just few day's back and what i did is, just deleted the **android-support-v4.jar** from my project, and then i have added my library project jar by right clicking my project -> go to properties, select java Build Path and then select **add external jar** from the option and select **android-support-v4.jar** from your library project and then click on **Order and export** and check mark **android-support-v4.jar** that you have added from library project and then press Ok.

That's it. Enjoy Coding