# Errors with eclipse & ADT Version

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been working in eclipse on my android app.

I have opened the IDE today and got this message:

[image]

I tried to update the eclipse (Help ==> updates)

but not updates were found.

Then i have clicked on the SDK-manager and updated the SDK as requested.

I have restarted my IDE and yet I get these errors:

[image]

**update**

I did what @Daan suggested

but then I got:

[image]

Comment: edited my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

Go to Help -> Install new software -> fill in this URL

> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

download all Developer Tools and NDK Plugins, restart and it should work again.

===========================================================================

**UPDATE AFTER UPDATE MAIN QUESTION**

Found a simulair question about the error you got after u tried the above:

Answer:

> Delete android-support-v4.jar from library and project. Then go in
>   /extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos/ and copy
>   android-support-v4.jar and paste in libs folder of both.

Source:

> [Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list appcompat in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450086/found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar-in-the-dependency-list-appcompat-in-a)

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered before in :

[Error Message : This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513524/error-message-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6/22706130#22706130)

However, this is the fix

The problem is that the default update site in Android ADT is

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

but this site don't update correctly

And the solution is add a new Install site with protocol https

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Click in Help->Install New Software->Add

And use this site to update ADT

Issue : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67325