# Jar dependency error when importing android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I am trying to import an external project into Eclipse for further coding.
Once the project was import, following errors were found:

```
found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list appcompat in  android.
```

Then, I have studied this link and found the solution.
[Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list appcompat in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450086/found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar-in-the-dependency-list-appcompat-in-a)

I have deleted the `android-support-v4.jar` in library folder of the project but I cannot find
`<sdk>/extras/android/support/samples/Support4Demos/` and copy `android-support-v4.jar` to replace the original file. Can anyone tell me the location???

Besides, are there any standard steps for importing an android project in the latest version of adt?? I find that there are many people has the similar problem but the solutions provided by others were so different. I am a bit lost about the correct steps.

Comment: android-support-v4.jar usually inserted into  android-support-v7 file. you can find it there. and for this check your targeted work space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056914/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies)

Comment: I have tried to follow the steps of Muhannad A.Alhariri in above link but errors come out when I add external Jars.

'Setting build path' has encounter a problem. Could not write file:
 C:\Users\Users\workspace\ICEAPP\.classpath.

Comment: I have tried to removed the .classpath file but one of source code file still shows "does not resolved"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it really easy way: Firstly, I've checked which of the libraries android-support-v4.jar was the last updated. Generally, you can check the modification date and also the size of the file (normally, not always, the last version is heavier than the older versions).

Ok, you already have the last one? ok, replace (copy/paste) this .jar file in all the projects . The error will dissapear.

At least, for me was the solution. You need to have the same .jar file in all the projects imported and main project.

Clean all the project and build again!!!!